# Chat server mysql query on new client

Tags: python, twisted, mysql-python

I have a simple chat server and i want to query my db whenever a new client connects. I tried with twistar CRUD interface but i got a strange error:

exceptions.NameError: global name 'result' is not defined

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twistar.registry import Registry
from twistar.dbobject import DBObject

Registry.DBPOOL = adbapi.ConnectionPool('MySQLdb', host="localhost", db="testdb", user="test", passwd="test")
dbconfig = Registry.getConfig()

class Chat(LineReceiver):

    # Here is the callback
    def result(values):
        print values

    def __init__(self, users):
        self.users = users
        self.name = None
        self.state = "GETNAME"

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.sendLine("What's your name?")

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        if self.users.has_key(self.name):
            del self.users[self.name]

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        if self.state == "GETNAME":
            self.handle_GETNAME(line)
        else:

    def handle_GETNAME(self, name):
        if self.users.has_key(name):
            self.sendLine("Name taken, please choose another.")
            return
        self.sendLine("Welcome, %s!" % (name,))
        # Here is the query
        d = dbconfig.select("testtable").addCallback(result)**

        self.name = name
        self.users[name] = self
        self.state = "CHAT"

    def handle_CHAT(self, message):
        message = "<%s> %s" % (self.name, message)
        for name, protocol in self.users.iteritems():
            if protocol != self:
                protocol.sendLine(message)

def result(var):
       print var

class ChatFactory(Factory):

    def __init__(self):
        self.users = {} # maps user names to Chat instances

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Chat(self.users)

reactor.listenTCP(8000, ChatFactory())
reactor.run()
```

Outside of the chat server the CRUD db query works without any problem.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I see two "result" methods defined underneath the Chat class, but since they are not indented so I cannot tell what is going on there.

Comment: They are idented as the should be.

Answer (score 2):

If result is a member of the class, it must be prefaced with self.

```
 d = dbconfig.select("testtable").addCallback(self.result)**
```

Comment: Due i am a noob with python i tried to modify as you suggested. Now the error is "self.result = callback(self.result, *args, **kw)
exceptions.TypeError: result() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)". Can you help ?

Comment: It's hard to tell because your indentation is messed up, but if result is a member function, it needs self as an argument. def result(self,var)

Comment: I think the first result is a member function, whilst the second was not. I've proposed an edit to reflect this. Based on that assumption, the first result should be `def result(self, values):`

Comment: @neppoz, member functions (that are in a class) require the first paramater to be `self`. This assumed parameter is automatically populated so that when you call `self.result(blah)` it becomes `result(self, blah)`. Your error was saying that you're passing 2 values to a function that only expects 1 as you're missing the `self` paramater in the definition.